# Sending 2 streams to FFmpeg from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, google-speech-api, web-audio-api

I am trying to send 2 [ReadableStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) to FFmpeg from nodejs. I have tried using fluent-ffmpeg library to do this, but it only supports sending one stream for processing. Check [here](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/536)

My problem is:
I have 2 incoming mono audio streams, I want to send them to ffmpeg to create a stereo stream, which I will then send to google's speech to text service, to generate a transcription.

I am successfully receiving both the mono streams to the nodejs server.
How to utilize FFmpeg to merge them in realtime is still unclear, I could spawn a FFmpeg child process, but I'm not sure how to give 2 [ReadableStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) as inputs and get the output as another stream? FFmpeg supports multiple input streams.

I can merge the 2 mono streams if they are in two separate files with this code.

```
const { spawn } = childProcess;
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i', this.phoneAudioFile,
  '-i', this.micAudioFile,
  '-filter_complex', '[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]',
  '-map', '[a]',
  this.outputLosslessFile,
]);
```

How can I acheive the same using 2 streams instead of 2 files?

**EDIT**

- The incoming streams both have PCM audio data.
- This entire process runs on a linux Ubuntu server.
- The final output must be a wav file.

Comment: You should tell us what platform you're on, and what that source audio format is.  Named pipes can often be used, but they have quirks and aren't available everywhere.

Comment: I added more info to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your source audio streams are regular PCM audio (such as what is most commonly found in WAV files), I would merge the streams internally in your application, and output a single stream to FFmpeg.

This can be done as simply as alternating which stream you read from, effectively interleaving the samples.

If your samples are 16-bit, then each sample is two bytes.  So, your stream will look like this:

```
[LL][RR][LL][RR][LL][RR]
```

(where each `LL` is 2 bytes of a single sample for the left channel, and the same for `RR`)

If you're going to pipe this into FFmpeg, you'll need to set up the appropriate parameters for RAW PCM.  Or, you can generate a WAV file header in your application as well.